# How to use bower installed widget in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

Hi everyone this might be a stupid question but i am not sure how to proceed thats why i am asking the question here.

I wants to use bootstrap-calendar in my yii2 project. I installed all the necessary files using the command given on the project page with help of `bower`.

Dependency are listed automatically and all the `jquery` and `css` files are installed in `vendor` folder. So now how do i use that widget in `yii2` view file?

Do i just use it like any other `js` and `css` files i use?

I mean using `AppAsset` or do i manually include the files required to use the plugin like below?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../vendor/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../vendor/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../calendar.js"></script>
```

I am really confused with this.

Comment: It's not much, but do you read this: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md ?

Comment: @TomaszKane thank you for that doc its helpful for me but it doesnt have calendar events ui so i cant use that here.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use bower assets directly.

As you've probably noticed, they are installed in the `vendor` folder which is outside your web root. Making a copy of certain files from `vendor` folder to the web-accessible `web/assets` folder is called *asset publishing*. It is implemented using yii's `AssetBundle` class. `AssetBundle` also handles *asset registration*, which is the process of creating `script` and `style` tags in your HTML document.

A typical example of asset publishing is the `BootstrapAsset` class:

```
class BootstrapAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/bootstrap/dist';
    public $css = [
        'css/bootstrap.css',
    ];
}
```

This configuration instructs yii to publish contents of the `dist` directory to a temporary web-accessible location. Also, when this asset is registered in a view (`BootstrapAsset::register($this)`), a corresponding `style` tag to include `bootstrap.css` will be created.

This topic is [extensively covered in the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html).

However, it's most likely that somebody has already taken all these steps and already created the corresponding asset bundle and possibly widget. In your particular case, consider these two date picker widgets:

- https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget
- https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker